# Ubuntu does not boot after update

Tags: grub2, updates, realtek, dkms

I run an Ubuntu Jammy using 5.15.0.47 kernel under an Asrock J4005 (embedded cpu).
After an update and a restart, the boot process stop (monitor says no signal).
I remove the quiet and splash from grub menu option
I can see a bunch of information but no obvious error.

Using recovery mode I was able to grab an update error (dkms crash log) linked to my embedded network card (realtek r8168). The error was a gcc version mismatch between the kernel one and the realtek module one.
I configure Ubuntu to use gcc11 instead of gcc8 and I was able to rebuild r8168-dkms.
After this step I am still not able to made a normal boot.
I can start in recovery mode and after that choose the "Try to resume to normal boot" from the recovery menu.
By doing that I found a fully working Ubuntu.

How can I find why the normal boot process does not work? To start this computer using the  recovery mode is not an option because I use this computer as a server without screen and keyboard

I found this file: r8168-dkms.0.crash

```
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for r8168-8.049.02 for kernel 5.15.0-47-generic (x86_64)
 Mo 05 Sep 2022 16:32:48 CEST
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic'
 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
   The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
   You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 8.5.0-0ubuntu4) 8.5.0
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_asf.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtl_eeprom.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtltool.o
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_asf.o] Error 1
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtl_eeprom.o] Error 1
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtltool.o] Error 1
 make: *** [Makefile:1881: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.15.0-47-generic
Date: Mon Sep  5 16:32:50 2022
DuplicateSignature: dkms:r8168-dkms:8.049.02-1ubuntu1:gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
Package: r8168-dkms 8.049.02-1ubuntu1
PackageVersion: 8.049.02-1ubuntu1
SourcePackage: r8168
Title: r8168-dkms 8.049.02-1ubuntu1: r8168 kernel module failed to build
```

What others file can be usefull? dmesg? some /var/syslog files? During the boot process the screen just shutdown without displaying an error.

Thank you

Comment: We need the full text of errors. Don't paraphrase them in your own words. If it's impossible to copy/paste, you can post a screenshot.

Comment: I edit my question